# Can time be described as a distance?

Tags: time, coordinate-systems, measurements

Can we do away with time in the coordinate system? When I picture the x,y and z planes and plot positions, the idea of adding a time element seems redundant. The time element adds a reference to an event outside the planes. Which is another distance measure - how far something moved such as a clock hand. We can see changing locations in the planes without the outside movement reference. The question of how fast something moves is the ratio of two distance measures, the clock hand to the movement in the plane. I’m sure this is not a novel thought. Is the time element necessary? Is time really a measure of distance?

Comment: Interesting reads: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_time

Comment: In special relativity, the invariant spacetime distance is $(\Delta s)^{2} \; = \; - (\Delta c t)^{2} + (\Delta x)^{2} + (\Delta y)^{2} + (\Delta z)^{2}$. The minus sign tells us that time is different from space

Comment: Time has been a hyperbolic distance for over a century: https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01234449/document